# How to make an arrow next to a pseudo:hover::before element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

This is my code

```css
.privacycheck1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 265px;
  background-color: #CF0000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 843px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px #E60000;
}
.privacycheck1::before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 30px;
}
.privacycheck1:hover::before {
  content: 'This information is private';
  width: 125px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #CF0000;
  left: 40px;
  top: -10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="privacycheck1"></div>
```

I want to make it so when someone `hovers` over the `privacycheck1`, I want them to see an arrow connecting to the box pointing at `privacycheck1`'s circle.
Is there anyway to make a class in a class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra `span` element to create this.

First create the tail of the arrow using the span and then create the arrow head using the border-hack on the after pseudo-element. You can find a wide range of arrows **[here](http://css-shapes.xyz/arrows)**

```css
.privacycheck1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #CF0000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px #E60000;
}
.privacycheck1::before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 30px;
}
.privacycheck1:hover::before {
  content: 'This information is private';
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #CF0000;
  left: 40px;
  top: -10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  display:none;
}
.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
  left:15px;
  top:-2px;
  display:none;
  }
.privacycheck1:hover span,.privacycheck1:hover span:after{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="privacycheck1"><span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra span. You can use an :after just like you used a :before.

```
.privacycheck1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #CF0000;
 }
```

If you use top: 50%; and margin-top negative half the arrow height it will always be perfectly aligned in the vertical center. In this case I gave the arrow height: 30px; so the margin-top is -15px

Oh and you made a mistake in you hover:before. 'font-weight: 100px;' doesn't exist, you can use 'bold', '700' or another value.

Another tip, add this to your hover:before

```
left: calc(100% + 15px);
```

This way your box will always have the right distance between the 'dot' and the text box. The box will use the width of the parent (the element with position: relative;) + 15px (the width of the arrow) to align from the left.